# fragment transaction cannot be applied to

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Hi guys I am having problem with my fragment. I am just new to android development so please spare me. here what it says.

```
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();

    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

    transaction.add(R.id.my_layout, fragment, "alvin");

    transaction.commit();

}
```

I am having problem on the "transaction.add();" part. It says **"fragment transaction cannot be applied to."**

I don't know why but heres my `MyFragment.java` -

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MyFragment extends Fragment{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment_layout, container, false);
    }
}
```

and my activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#00BBFF"
    android:id="@+id/my_layout">



</RelativeLayout>

my_fragment_layout.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFBB00">

    <TextView
        android:layout_margin="40dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="MY FRAGMENT"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

heres my android manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.serverus.fragmentexperiment" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I just want to see my fragment running on my device please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: The activity should extend `FragmentActivity`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Replace

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
```

by

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
```

The `MyFragment` class is a [support Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html), which you can see by inspecting the import statement

> import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

Comment: `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;`
import android.view.MenuItem;
 
then

`FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();`

that works for me. thanks